# Filling array from xml? PHP/XML

Tags: php, arrays, xml

I try to fill a specific array from a xml file.

This is my xml structure with two articles:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-productexport>

  <article key="5817203" status="active">
    <productattributes>
      <not_visible>
        <feature key="product-type">
          <xx description="Product-Type">Fix cable</xx>
        </feature>
        <feature key="headline_datasheet">
          <xx description="Headline Datasheet">Fix cable, M12, S400</xx>
        </feature>
        <feature key="model">
          <xx description="Model">axial</xx>
        </feature>
      </not_visible>
      <group1>
        <feature key="article_description">
          <xx description="Article Description">BDX991-S400</xx>
        </feature>
        <feature key="_name">
          <xx description="Name">5817203</xx>
        </feature>
      </group1>
    </productattributes>
  </article>

  <article key="5817204" status="active">
    <productattributes>
      <not_visible>
        <feature key="product-type">
          <xx description="Product-Type">Fix cable</xx>
        </feature>
        <feature key="headline_datasheet">
          <xx description="Headline Datasheet">Fix cable, M12, S340</xx>
        </feature>
        <feature key="model">
          <xx description="Model">axial</xx>
        </feature>
      </not_visible>
      <group1>
        <feature key="article_description">
          <xx description="Article Description">DDX991-S340</xx>
        </feature>
        <feature key="_name">
          <xx description="Name">5817204</xx>
        </feature>
      </group1>
    </productattributes>
  </article>

</web-productexport>
```

From this I need every value from a article in the following array structure:

```
$article = array(
    'name' => 'BDX991-S400',
    'active' => true,
    'tax' => 19,
    'supplier' => 'Conrad',    
    ),
    'mainDetail' => array(
        'number' => '5817203',
        'active' => true
        )
    ),
);
```

So I need to fill it like this:
name = value of Article Description (BDX991-S400), number = value of Name (5817203)

This is my php file:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "XXX";
$password = "XXX";
$dbname = "XXX";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("\n\n### ERROR! ###" . $conn->connect_error);}

$xmlstring = simplexml_load_file("FILEPATH");

foreach($xmlstring->children() as $article) {
    echo $articleid = (string) $article['key'];
    foreach($article->children() as $productattr) {
        foreach($productattr->children() as $visible)
            foreach($visible->children() as $group) {
                foreach($group->children() as $xx) {
                $values=$xx;
                echo $values;
             }
          }
      }
}
```

I put the values of xx into the string "**$values**", but I don't know how i can get this values into the specific array mentioned above.

Can someone help me? I'm stuck..

Or should I change the structure of my xml export?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make the job easier by using what you know about the structure and referencing nested elements as you need them rather than looping over all of the child nodes.  Also using `$xmlstring->article` is more explicit that you want the `<article>` elements under that level rather than any other data.

This just adds in the variable data, you will need to add the relevant other bits to your output...

```
$xmlstring = simplexml_load_file("data.xml");

$output = [];
foreach($xmlstring->article as $article) {
    $articleData = [];
    foreach ( $article->productattributes->group1->feature as $feature )   {
        if ( $feature['key'] == "article_description" ) {
            $articleData['name'] = (string)$feature->xx;
        }
        else if ( $feature['key'] == "_name" ) {
            $articleData['mainDetail']['number'] = (string)$feature->xx;
        }
    }
    $output[] = $articleData;
}

print_r($output);
```

This outputs...

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => BDX991-S400
            [mainDetail] => Array
                (
                    [number] => 5817203
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => DDX991-S340
            [mainDetail] => Array
                (
                    [number] => 5817204
                )

        )

)
```

Also note that I had to fix a couple of the attributes as you have.

```
<xx ="Product-Type">Fix cable</xx>
```

which is missing the name of the attribute.